# Shape glass effect

Tags: android, gradient, shapes

I've created a custom toolbar using a gradient inside a shape.  It looks very nice, but since we only have the option for 3 colors (startColor, centerColor, endColor) it looks very round.  I would like to do a glass effect, which requires a sharp change in color in the middle.  Basically I need 4 colors (startColor, justabovecenterColor, justbelowcenterColor, endColor).  Now I could have two shapes sitting on top of each other to get this effect, but I don't want to do this.  I'm getting into some tricky UI customization here and that would be very difficult to manage on different sized screens.

Does anyone know how I can create a glass effect?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [NinePatch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) ? This would be a quick and easy way to make a good looking, scalable set of shapes...